# Passing data from bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, function

I am trying to pass the data from bootstrap model and display it on a table. However, the problem here is I am unable to pass the data and the column only display null values. I am a newbie, so I need some help on how to pass the data Day and Session?

```
<table class="table order-list" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Day
      </th>
      <th>
        Type
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>

</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div id="daypicker" class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <h5>Select A Day: </h5>
          <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" multiple data-max-options="1" data-live-search="true">
            <optgroup label="Day">
              <option>Monday</option>
              <option>Tuesday</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
          <h5>Select A Session: </h5>
          <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" multiple data-max-options="1" data-live-search="true">
            <optgroup label="Session">
              <option>Morning</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
          </br>
          </br>
        </div>
      </div>
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="addrow" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Day' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Session' + counter + '"/></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You left out the button to add rows

Comment: <button id="addrow" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>

Comment: it's already there, i just need to know how to pass the value to append new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You haven't closed the  tag correctly for the "#addrow" button.
2. You can extract the values from the modal like so (after you give the `<select>` elements a proper id:

   `var dayPickerSelect1 = $("#daypicker-select1").val();`

   `var dayPickerSelect2 = $("#daypicker-select2").val();`
3. You can then pass the extracted values to the table like so:

   `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Day' + counter + '" value="' + dayPickerSelect1 + '"/>`

   `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Session' + counter + '" value="' + dayPickerSelect2 + '"/>`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, anyhow, how can i pass the data of Day and Session to 

 cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Day' + counter + '"/></td>';

Comment: I've edited the answer with some more tips. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, i test something you have told me 
 <input type="text" placeholder ='Start Time' id="#daypicker-select1" name="valueId"/> but the problem is when i click enter, i get an undefined value